# About responsive, reactive and asynchronous front-end

Tags: rest, responsive

Suppose you have a front-end web application that needs show a list made up of three web API calls (A, B and C).

I need to display those results as soon as the response from those APIs arrive. However I have a BFF in the middle.

Here are three alternatives I imagine:

1. The Front-End call to the BFF and it sequentially calls A, B and C. So the total response time is A + B + C, so this is not de better solution to  the problem.
2. The Front-End call to BFF and It parallel call to A & B & C, so the total response time is equal to slow service. That is a better approach.
3. I envision one last scenario where the Front-End calls BFF and the BFF calls A, B and C in in parallel however the BFF sends the results to the Front-End as they arrive. So if the results fetched from, say, B web API, the BFF immediately sends back to the front-end to allow It display those results, and in the background, the BFF continues to process the others web API results to, in a progressive way, continues to send back to the front-end that results.

My question is: what is the better way to achieve that architecture?

An answer, best practices, or a discussion of the solution to the problem posed.

Comment: BFF -- Best friend forever?